How to preview LiveActivity using swiftui Previewer?
As seen in the WWDC 24 video, it's possible to visualize all live activity UIs in the previewer. However, I'm encountering a Cannot preview this file error.
struct LiveActivityTest: Widget {
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        ActivityConfiguration(for: CustomLAData.self, content: {context in
            VStack{
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .resizable()
                Text("Text 1")
            }
        }, dynamicIsland: {context in
            let timeRange = Date()...Date.now+100
            return DynamicIsland{
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.leading, content: {
                    Text("Text 1")
                        .bold()
                })

                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.trailing, content: {
                        Text(timerInterval: timeRange, pauseTime: timeRange.lowerBound, countsDown: true)
                            .font(.system(size: 22,weight: .bold))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                })

                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom){
                    Text("Bottom Text")
                }

            } compactLeading: {
                Text("Compact leading")
            } compactTrailing: {
                Image(systemName:"globe")
            } minimal: {
                Image(systemName:"globe")
            }
        })
    }
}

#Preview(as: .dynamicIsland(.compact), using: CustomLAData(), widget: {
    LiveActivityTest()
}, contentStates: {
    CustomLAData.State()
    CustomLAData.State(isLoading:true)
})

struct CustomLAData : ActivityAttributes{
    typealias ContentState = State

    struct State : Codable,Hashable{
        var isLoading = false
    }
}

I tried using different preview macros, but I still couldn't identify where I made a mistake
Note : I have added the Liveactivity widget to widget bundle.
Target membership


I tried your Widget within a WidgetExtension and it worked fine. Can you show the folder and the file target membership?

@sonle i have added the target membership details.

question !  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78742542/for-a-live-activity-how-can-i-put-my-widget-bundle-widgetbundle-in-a-target
